# Manipulating data stored in an array when input via a web form

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, methods, console.log

I am trying to manipulate data I have stored as a string in an array when it's input via a web form. I am getting inconsistent results, and I am not sure why. When I tell the data to console.log via a 'for loop,' it works, but when I try to console.log a specific index from the array, I am getting "undefined."

HTML and Javascript are below:

**HTML**

```
<head>

</head>    
<body>

    <form id="form">
        <label for="html_input">Input Your HTML</label>
        <input type="text" id="html_input" name="html_input">
        <button type="submit">Submit HTML</button>
    </form>
    <p id="output"></p>
    
    
    <script src=sample.js></script>

</body>
```

**JS**

```
const tag_array = [];


function formSubmit(event) {
  const input = document.getElementById("html_input").value;
  tag_array.push(input.split("<"));
  //the below console.log works
  console.log(tag_array);
  //the below is returning undefined
  console.log(`index 1: ${tag_array[1]}`);
  //the below for loop and console.log works
  for (let i = 0; i < tag_array.length; i++) {
    console.log(tag_array[i]);
  };

  log.textContent = input;
  event.preventDefault();
  };



const form = document.getElementById('form');
const log = document.getElementById('output');
form.addEventListener('submit', formSubmit);
```

**What I am pasting into the submit form to try to manipulate:**

````
<body margin="0" border="0" style="color:#555555; font-family: Arial, 
  Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: .7em;">
    
<!---- PRE-HEADER ------>
<p id="preheader" style="display: none; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:1px;">Proud American deals just for you! Today only, take up to $15 off Vera Bradley Military Collection handbags, 20 percent off Columbia PFG Fishing USA Flag caps, USA and military flags and more, all at shopmyexchange.com and in select stores. Shop now!</p>
<!---- /PRE-HEADER ------>
    
<!-- Email Wrapper Table -->
    
<table align="center" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" margin="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;">```
````

Comment: Well, for the very first element, `tag_array[1]` will be `undefined` because the array contains only one item and it is `tag_array[ 0 ]` not `tag_array[ 1 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what you are looking for [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

missing on: `tag_array.push(input.split("<"));`
to replace by: `tag_array.push(...input.split("<"));`
as array push doesn't accept array value as argument.

complete code (ES6)

```js
const myForm    = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ,   myLog     = document.getElementById('my-log')
  ,   tag_array = []

myForm.onsubmit=e=>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  tag_array.push(...myForm.html_input.value.split('<'))
  myLog.textContent = myForm.html_input.value
  myForm.html_input.value = ''
  
  console.clear()
  tag_array.forEach((elm,i)=> console.log(`index ${i}: ${elm}`))
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <label >Input Your HTML</label>
  <input type="text" name="html_input">
  <button type="submit">Submit HTML</button>
</form>
<p id="my-log"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your code: `tag_array` only has one element, the array of string segments.

You don't need to use `.push()`, you should just assign to the array:

```js
const input = 'tag1<tag2<tag3';
const tag_array = input.split('<');

console.log(tag_array);
// ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']

for (let i = 0; i < tag_array.length; i++) {
  console.log(tag_array[i]);
  // 'tag1', ...
};
```